# Text in footer on first page, but no page numbers

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

For a `documentclass{article}` document, I would like to print a word on the right edge of my footer on the first page, otherwise I would like all headers and footers to be empty (no page numbers). I assume I can use `fancyhdr` to accomplish this, but the documentation is a little beyond me (it contains a few examples, but it doesn't explain what all the different options are or what they do).

Comment: The Wikibook LaTeX section [Page Layout: Customising with `fancyhdr`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customising_with_fancyhdr) (which is among the first Google hits for "fancyhdr") might help you with using `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` for the first page, and `\pagestyle{empty}` for the rest:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
\fancyfoot[R]{Word}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
​
```

Answer (score 6):

With `fancyhdr` you can declare a page style to contain the special footer and declare this pagestyle for the first page; for the other pages you can use the `empty` page style. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\fancypagestyle{specialfooter}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{Some special text}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{specialfooter}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]